# How can I move my navigation bar to a different place?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm trying to make my nav bar be horizontal and *centered.* Right now, it's all smushed to the right of the website. How do I control where the bar is located?
Also, why can't I just have all my css under #nav (why do I need #nav ul li, etc?)

```css
#nav{
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li a{
    padding: 40px;
    background: #25ccc7;
    color: white;         
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's centered here. The other part of the question I don't really understand. When you style `#nav` you style the div with that id. `#nav ul li` styles the li elements inside it. You may shorted it by using just `#nav li`, but no less than that. If you have just `#nav` you styled the div instead of the nav items, and having just `li` without `#nav` styles all `li` elements, regardless of where they are on your page.

Comment: 1) CSS is hierarchical (the "cascade" in "Cascading Style Sheets").  You don't *need* "#nav ul li, etc".  2) You don't need that redundant "text-align: center" in the same stanza, eitgher. 3) Look here for several different tips on "centering": https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, or here: http://howtocenterincss.com/.  FINALLY: Always try your CSS on several *different* browsers.  Unfortunately, different browsers can and will often render your layout differently.

Comment: The comments contain alot of useful information for you so far. Yet all fail to realize what cause your position problem. I addressed that in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need the different css selectors because not all the styles are meant to be applied to the surrounding container `#nav`, but to certain elements *inside* it. With pure CSS, it is **not possible to nest rules**. If nesting is what you were asking for, take a look at LESS or SASS ([DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=LESS%20SASS&t=ffsb&ia=qa) is your friend).

Your list items were pushed a little to the right because that is the natural behaviour of list items unless you overwrite the responsible css attributes `margin` and / or `padding` (depending on the browser). So just reset both to `0` in your CSS for the list items.

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li a {
  padding: 40px;
  background: #25ccc7;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```